# Aurora Serverless currently doesn't support CloudWatch Log Expor

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

I have created several `DBs` in `RDS` in the past using:

```
Engine: aurora-postgresql
EngineMode: serverless
EngineVersion: 10.12
```

And exporting the logs:

```
EnableCloudwatchLogsExports:
  - postgresql
```

However, today I tried to do the same and I'm receiving the following error in CloudFormation:

```
Aurora Serverless currently doesn't support CloudWatch Log Export. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: dcc380c4-1079-4932-9395-09c0bc64ba2b; Proxy: null)
```

This is something new. I created a Db last week and I didn't have any issues.

Are you aware of any change?

I tried upgrading/downgrading the `EngineVersion` but I still receive that error.

Comment: We started having very similar errors. Any luck about what is causing it? Thanks.